# How do I clear volcanic crusts?

Tags: all-my-gods

I need to clear some volcanic crusts so I can have some more space to build.

I know that it is theoretically possible, because when I hover over them, it says "Can be cleared." Normally I would just use the Hand of God, but it doesn't seem to work here, and I can't tell my workers to do anything about it either.

How do I make them disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to research "draining the swamp" and then you can set a worker to clear the crust with it. By using this the worker will take the square and transform it into a solid and buildable surface.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think that swamps and volcanic crust were the same, so I was putting it off because I didn't have any swamps around. :)

Comment: @AshleyNunn Yeah, I guess they mean molton magma swamps haha. Very misleading.